# Combine all elements of a list and retain only unique values

Tags: r, list

I have a data frame `SCC` with several columns.  From these columns I wanted to find all the rows that have the word "coal" in them.

I use the `grep` function to do so and stored results in variable `x` (a list) with the following command:

```
x <- sapply(SCC, grep, pattern="coal", ignore.case=T)
```

Now `x` tells me where in the data frame the word "coal" occurs, it is a list and the 4th and the 9th elements of this list are given below.

```
> x[4]
$EI.Sector
 [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
[17]  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  80  81
[33]  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98
[49]  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 161 162
[65] 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178
[81] 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 215 221 433 434 435 447 448 462 463
[97] 527 528 529

> x[9]
$SCC.Level.Three
  [1]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13
 [14]   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   79   80   81   83   84
 [27]   85   86   87   88   89   90   91   92   93   94   95   96   97
 [40]   98   99  100  101  102  103  104  105  161  162  163  164  165
 [53]  166  167  168  169  170  171  172  173  174  175  176  177  178
 [66]  179  180  242  433  434  435  447  448  462  463  477  478  527
 [79]  528  529 2220 2221 2222 2223 2224 2496 2497 2498 2499 2500 2501
 [92] 2502 2503 2504 2505 2506 2591 2592 4520 4673 4674 4675 4676 4677
[105] 4678 4679 4680 7415 7416 7417 7418 7419 7420 7421 7422 7423 7424
[118] 7425 7426 7427 7428 7429 7430 7431 7432 7433 7434 7435 7436 7437
[131] 7438 7439 7440 7441 7442 7443 7444 7445 7446 7447 7448 7449 7450
[144] 7451 7452 7453 7454 7455 7456 7457 7458 7459 7460 7461 7462 7991
[157] 7992 7993 7994 7995 7996 7997 7998 7999 8000 8001 8002 8003 8004
[170] 8005 8006 8007 8008 8009 9054 9055 9056 9057 9058 9059 9060
```

**Question 1**

I want to combine `x[4]` and `x[9]` into one index; how should I proceed? I am right now using below code, but is there a more concise command?

```
y <- x[[4]] %in% intersect(x[[4]], x[[9]])
z <- c( x[[4]][!y], x[[9]])

> sort(z)
  [1]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
 [13]   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24
 [25]   25   26   27   28   29   30   79   80   81   83   84   85
 [37]   86   87   88   89   90   91   92   93   94   95   96   97
 [49]   98   99  100  101  102  103  104  105  106  107  108  109
 [61]  110  111  112  161  162  163  164  165  166  167  168  169
 [73]  170  171  172  173  174  175  176  177  178  179  180  181
 [85]  182  183  184  185  215  221  242  433  434  435  447  448
 [97]  462  463  477  478  527  528  529 2220 2221 2222 2223 2224
[109] 2496 2497 2498 2499 2500 2501 2502 2503 2504 2505 2506 2591
[121] 2592 4520 4673 4674 4675 4676 4677 4678 4679 4680 7415 7416
[133] 7417 7418 7419 7420 7421 7422 7423 7424 7425 7426 7427 7428
[145] 7429 7430 7431 7432 7433 7434 7435 7436 7437 7438 7439 7440
[157] 7441 7442 7443 7444 7445 7446 7447 7448 7449 7450 7451 7452
[169] 7453 7454 7455 7456 7457 7458 7459 7460 7461 7462 7991 7992
[181] 7993 7994 7995 7996 7997 7998 7999 8000 8001 8002 8003 8004
[193] 8005 8006 8007 8008 8009 9054 9055 9056 9057 9058 9059 9060
```

**Question 2**

There are other columns with the word "coal" in `SCC`.  Length of the elements of `x` gives us and idea of where the word "coal" is used in `SCC`.  Is there a single command to combine all the elements of `x` to generate row index?

```
sapply(x, NROW)
                SCC       Data.Category          Short.Name 
                  0                   0                 239 
          EI.Sector        Option.Group          Option.Set 
                 99                   0                   0 
      SCC.Level.One       SCC.Level.Two     SCC.Level.Three 
                  0                   0                 181 
     SCC.Level.Four              Map.To Last.Inventory.Year 
                126                   0                   0 
       Created_Date        Revised_Date         Usage.Notes 
                  0                   0                   0
```

Comment: union is does the job, is there a way to do union on all the element of x simultaneously? Thanks

Comment: All of them.  union() takes only to vector, is there another function that would take as argument all the elements of x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(making comments into answer)*

Are you not doing `z <- union(x[[4]], x[[9]])`?

> `union` does the job, is there a way to do union on all the element of `x` simultaneously?
>
> `union()` takes only two vectors; is there another function that would take as argument all the elements of `x`?

We can simply do

```
unique(unlist(x))
```

If you want to stay with using `union`, do:

```
Reduce(union, x)
```